# Child divs won't respond to percent height

Tags: html, css

So I was working on a website when I came across the problem of my footer not staying at the bottom of my container div (the footer was not inside of the container, it was placed after it in the HTML). I realized this was because some of the child divs were floated, so I had to put overflow:auto on the container--HOWEVER, because I needed the children to have percentage heights, I had the height at 100%, and as you probably know *overflow:auto + specified height = scrollbar*. But having just a min-height wouldn't allow the child divs to get their height. Having both certainly doesn't work.

I recreated the problem in some separate testing files, getting rid of all the unnecessary CSS (although I'm sure some still remains) so I could visualize the problem without clutter. [**It's on this JSFiddle currently.**](http://jsfiddle.net/4usub45f/3/) I have the height commented out currently, because ideally I won't be using it.

Here's my container div CSS:

```
  #container {
    position: relative;
    width: 70%;
    /*height:100%;*/
    min-height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color:#FFDA8A;
  }
```

And one of the child divs that needs a percentage height:

```
.featured {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
  background-color:red;
}
```

EDIT: I want to add that I know *why* this is happening, rather that I was wondering if anybody has stumbled upon a CSS-only way of dealing with it. If it can't be percentages, then I'll look into flex-boxes instead (as mentioned by PiniH, thanks!).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an old question, with no really good answer, usually when stuff get like this, you should use flex boxes in the end, the min-height property will not affect the children, unless it's a table, and then it gets a mess.

You can add:

```
 #container {
    position: relative;
    width: 70%;
    /*height:100%;*/
    min-height: 100%;
    height: 1px;
    overflow: auto;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color:#FFDA8A;
  }
```

But then it won't grow which I guess is why you used min-height in the first place.

I have been boggling my mind around this for a while, eventually I think flex is the only answer in this case.

Comment: The answer is because percentage values of properties are a **percentage of their parent**. The parent doesn't have a height set so the child is trying to be 50% height of nothing, and 50%/0 = 0.